# Hibernate map MySQL SET type

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

There is SET (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) type field in table: `SET('A','B')`.
And enum:

```
public enum Foo {
 A, B
}
```

So I want to map that field to `Set<Foo>`:

```
@Entity
public class Bar {
...
@Column(name="foos")
private Set<Foo> foos;
...
}
```

Or I want to know at least any way to read MySQL SET filed using Hibernate.

Comment: You shoukd use elementcollection annotation and set tagret type your enum class

Comment: Refer this if it helps you : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296537/mysql-set-datatype-column-to-java-set-mapping)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! Unfortunately, hibernate cannot handle database specific data types. (*At least I'm not unaware of it, so feel free to correct me :)*)

You can treat this as simple as `String` and parse it in getter:

```
@Entity
class Bar {
    ...
    @Column(name = "foos")
    private String foos;

    public Set<Foo> getFoos() {
        return (null == foos) ?
                Collections.emptySet() :
                Arrays.stream(foos.split(",")).map(Foo::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    ...
}
```

I admit, this is not really the *ORM/Hibernate-way* of doing things, but it does the job quite decently.

Comment: Thanks, but I decided to write custom AttributeConvertor using a similar to your approach.